# Host web app in Parse Server public folder

Tags: heroku, parse-server

My parse server is running on heroku and everything works great, and when I visit myapp.heroku.com I get the "I dream of being a website" text.

Question is, how do I run the web app in the public folder? I suspect I need to change something here...

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a parse server.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured this out quick... but incase someone else also falls into this pit.
use:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
});
```

also make sure you have express 4.8 or higher